# Как подключить к проекту несколько репозиториев через settings.xml?

Tags: maven, settings, репозиторий

Следующий кейс:
Проект настроен на один репозиторий. Нужна библиотека из другого репозитория.
Как настроить проект, чтобы он искал зависимость в другом репозитории?
Текущая настройка выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<settings>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>single_mirror</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>Mirror of Libr</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>single_mirror</id>
        <url>http://rep_url</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>Mirror of Libr</id>
        <name>Mirror of Libr</name>
        <url>http://rep_url</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Для чего нужно зеркало и сервер Mirror of Libr - я не знаю.
Его удаление за собой (вроде как) ничего не несёт.
Как добавить сюда ещё одну ссылку на другой репозиторий и настроить правильно ?

ЗЫ: settings.xml как-то связан с pom.xml (разраб сказал "нет")?

Comment: В файле `pom.xml` вашего проекта можно задать все необходимые репозитории с помощью тега [`<repositories>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories). Почему вы хотите сделать это именно через файл `settings.xml`?

Comment: Это не моё решение, использую то что есть. Есть настройка через settings.xml

Comment: Добавил в setting.xml профиль, репозиторий, зеркало.
Теперь получаю такую ошибку:

Could not transfer artifact **.****.*:***:pom:1.1.0 from/to mirror-id (mirror-url): transfer failed for 
https://mirror-url+path.pom

Причём последний адрес - рабочий. Кликаю по ниму и открывается браузер с XML.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить репозиторий в `settings.xml`, объявите его внутри профиля, и активируйте этот профиль:

```xml
<settings>
    ...
    <profiles>
        ...
        <profile>
            <id>myprofile</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>google</id>
                    <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Больше информации про подключение нескольких репозиториев можно найти [в официальном гайде](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).